# comparing decimal point values in if statement

Tags: ksh, floating-point

Today I was trying to compare two values and surprised what I saw. I didn't find any good suggestion anywhere. Could any one please help?

```
if [ 10.94 -gt 10 ]
then
  echo True
else
  echo False
fi
```

I am surprised here the result is False.

Then I tried the following.

```
if [[ 10.94 > 10 ]]
```

Result came as True. I was fine with it.

Again my script gave a flaw at a particular condition like below

```
if [[ 5.15 > 10 ]]
  echo True
fi
```

Here result came as True.

How come? Is there any better idea, which will compare the decimal values in a proper way?

Comment: `>` is a string comparison, `-gt` is arithmetic and only accepts integers.

Comment: @123 Thanks . Do you have any suggestion for Decimal values (Float)?

Comment: You can use bc or awk.

Comment: please suggest, in this case how can I use bc/awk command?

Comment: First example - you said: "*I am surprised here the result is False.*" I am surprised too, because `ksh` returns `True`

Comment: @techraf Not sure why in your Korn shell it is showing True. I am using Kornshell and getting value as False.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo | awk '{if (10.1 > 10.0) {print "True"} else {print "False"} }' 
True

if [ $(echo "10.12 < 10.13"|bc -l) -eq 1 ];then echo "True"; else echo "False"; fi
True
```

Comment: Hopefully the first solution will work in my script. The 2nd solution is not working in my shell. I ll try the first one. Thanks

Comment: what shell do you have?  I ve checked it on bash and ksh.